# Default values from SQL Server Express table column to Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-express

I am a new Database programming learner. I am using C# (.NET 3.5) along with SQL Server Express.

I am following Forms over Data Video Series from Microsoft. However, I am creating a databse, different from the one created in the videos.

In one of the tables, I wanted the present date/time to be inserted in the date column, so I am using the getdate() function as default value, which I have set using SQL Server Management Studio.  When I insert new rows in this table using  SQL Server Management Studio, the said column is updated fine.

However, when I use Windows form, and the auto-generated data grid for the dataset of this particular table, it does not update using the default value.

I think I am missing something in this. If somebody could point me in the right direction, it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why but I used the <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx>Data Video Series from Microsoft</a> tags in my post. It is showing fine in preview, but not in final post?!

Comment: Can you show how you're databinding the grid? How you're retrieving the dataset from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating your query, don't pass the date as a parameter, or alternatively, pass DateTime.Now or DateTime.UTCNow as your "current time"

Comment: Thanks for answer. However if I don't pass the date as a parameter, an exception is generated, as in the database table, that date is not allowed to be NULL. From where can I specify that it is OK if in Winform, date value is not there and the server will assign it properly?

Comment: What's your query for inserting the data?

Comment: Thanks again for answering. Nevermind, I think I got it... It was really stupid on my part... :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the default value of the column using GETDATE() I would not even have that column in the query, let SQL keep setting it for you. I hope I'm understanding your question correctly